# how to increment value inside Parse Object property of type "Object"

Tags: parse-server

I'm using Parse, and noticed ParseObject supports "increment(propertyName)", which is great for numeric properties. Let's say I have a property called "MyProp" of type Object, so it might look like this:

```
{
    stats: {
       counter1: 500,
       counter2: 600,
       counter3: 700
    },
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to increment counter1 inside MyProp property in an atomic way? e.g. something magical like object.increment("myProp.stats.counter1")?

Comment: Internally `increment()` works the same as `object.property += 1`. So, use it directly. Its atomic enough. Or you can even extend `ParseObject` class and override the increment function to look for inner objects.

Comment: but object.increment("myProp.stats.counter1") didn't work. It didn't throw any error either, it simply did nothing.

Comment: What I meant was, you can do - `object.get('myProp')['stats']['counter1'] += 1`, and this will do what you want. The node.js code is always single threaded, so you dont really need to worry about it being `atomic`

Comment: actually I do need to worry about atomicity, since I have a Parse cluster... In high loads, I've already seen multiple save requests for the same user coming to different servers. My solution eventually was to "patch" MongoTransform (part of the mongo storage adapter) and map the relevant $inc actions to underlying mongo updates of the sub documents..